# Dual output voltage from zener?

Tags: microcontroller, power-supply, voltage-regulator, ldo

One of my microcontroller projects requires dual outputs, 5V and 3.3V.

Instead of using a dedicated LDO for 3.3V, can a zener get the job done efficiently? Wouldn't that be easier and equally stable?

Any reason to stick with an LDO?

Thanks.
*Just so you know, current required for both voltages is 200ma.*
*Supply voltage from USB or 3.7V battery with boost.*

Comment: I'd just use two LDO's, unless the supply voltage was >6v. A zener is not "flat" at regulating current (volts will be a little higher with less current) but the real problem is, getting 200mA out of it. The zener will pass significant current, wasting significant power.

Comment: How do you intend to use it? A zener is a *shunt* regulator, and not very precise.

Comment: I have edited the question.

Comment: What model of microcontroller?  What do you need the 5V output for?  What do you need the 3.3V output for?  Why not unify to one voltage or the other?

Answer (score 4):

Can it be done with a Zener? Yes.

More efficiently?  NO!!!

Easier? NO!

Is a Zener more stable? Yes, but stability when using LDO is almost never a problem if you just place the decoupling caps as stated in the datasheet.

Any reason to use LDO: yes, all of the above, especially at 200 mA.

I strongly suggest using an LDO.
In case of a zener when the load is OFF and consuming no current, the 200 mA must be dissipated by the Zener which is wasteful and generates heat.
Just don't go that way. LDOs are cheap and easy. Everyone uses them.  Zener diodes were more popular decades ago when linear and switching regulators were more expensive. This cost differential has narrowed considerably.

Feeding the 3.3 V LDO from the 5 V LDO is generally a good idea (not always, see Asmyldof's comment), as it will share the dissipation between the LDOs which is what you want.

Comment: The feeding through the top Linear regulator (whether LDO or not) depends a bit on the supply voltage. If both voltages supply 200mA, then feeding through makes the top regulator (5V) dissipate the difference at 400mA which may be pushing it with a 12V input. In that case you want your 3.3V to come straight off the 12V as well, to more effectively share the dissipation.

Comment: Can a voltage level shifter also help in providing 3.3V with the required current?

Comment: No, level shifters are used to transport digital signals from one supply domain to another. So for example, you have chip A running at 3.3 V and chip B running at 5 V and you want to connect a digital signal from A to B (or B to A) then you need a levelshifter. Levelshifters have absolutely nothing to do with the supply itself.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the LDO .I found out the hard way .There was extreme PCB realestate pressure because the product had to be tiny and it had a 3V3 rail.I caved when the layout guy was having real space problems .He put in the 3V3 Zener and what was found was there was bad variability on the zeners due to voltage tolerances and weak or spongey knee characteristics .I was feeding the zener with about 100mA constant current source .I convinced the layout guy to use a 1watt part which shouldnt self heat too much and should have lower dynamic resistance .We lived with cherry picking on our very small hand assembled sample run .If this was a big production run we would have been in big trouble .We promptly      changed to a LDO to avoid the risk .The production run was to be encapsulated so risk was out of the question.I subsequently looked at some of the new SMD Zeners on the bench   and found them to be no better than the old zeners of yesteryear .There are semiconductor physics reasons why Zeners below about 6V progressively get more spongey at lower voltages.Maybe low volt zeners would be better constructed around a band gap reference .This was a real time warp for me because I banned 3V3 zeners in 1988 before I had to deal with 3V3 rails.